# HOW TO SCAN QR CODE FROM AN UPLOADED IMAGE IN UNITY?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, qr-code, game-development

I wanted to ask if it is possible to scan a qr code from an uploaded image? I'm making a unity sort of game that you can scan a qr code from the physical image for the character appear in the game. And it works.
But what if the character (image) is in the user's gallery and not the physical itself? I'm thinking that you can upload the image in the game so that it'll appear also, and that is the question, is it possible? I know some app that uses this technique but I don't know if unity can do this also

I'm using the zxing for this and this tutorial also for the scanning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43qt62TbY7E

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no such a built-in feature, but you can use external tools like [that one](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery). So when the target image file is retrieved you convert it to Color32[] and then use it just like the camera texture in tutorial you provided.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR TOUR ANSWER! I'll let you know if it works.